# Visual Studio: ctrl+shift+v opens clipboard ring window

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

I'm trying to get the clipboard ring working by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, but this only opens a window showing what the clipboard contains. I would like the items to cycle through as I press <kbd>V</kbd>, not open in a window.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> works as expected, and they both seems to be mapped to `Edit.CycleClipboardRing`, so why don't they behave the same way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is a ReSharper shortcut that's in conflict with your Visual Studio shortcuts. See if you can find a ReSharper shortcut mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, if you've got resharper installed

Comment: found it. it's called `ReSharper.ReSharper_PasteMultiple` in Tools > Options > Keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, found it too, finally. Thanks :)