# Ctrl-Shift-V not working in Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I was using VS 2012 in Windows 7. Yesterday, I installed Windows 8 and installed Visual Studio 2013.
And i can not use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> keys for Cycle Clipboard Ring. I have tried to assume manually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> keys for Cycle Clipboard Ring in Tools\Options\Keyboard menu. Still not working.

[SOLVED]- I have tried it in Design Window. It works fine in Code window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the Visual Studio Keyboard settings and make sure that the binding is setup correctly. You might have accidentally selected a different template the fist time you launched Visual Studio.

In my C# 2005 bindings, it's available. You might have to reset the mapping scheme and restart Visual Studio.

There might be a add-on, like Resharper that's interfering with the keybindings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done them and restart VS. Still, not working.

Answer (score 0):

The same story on Win7 and VS2013.
In my case helped only removing ReSharper.ReSharper_PasteMultiple shortcut.

Thanks to the thread:
[Visual Studio: ctrl+shift+v opens clipboard ring window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808590/visual-studio-ctrlshiftv-opens-clipboard-ring-window) I've coped with that.

ReSharper had been turned off nonetheless I had to totally remove the ReSharper's shortcut repeatedly pressing "Remove" (it was switching stacked values).